# Scale edges inward evenly

Tags: mesh, edges, scale

[image]

I don't know which title suit my question the best. But essentially what I'm trying to do is to create an indentation inward for each piece of wood that encircle my barrel. The only solution I find so far is to manually edit every single edge, but there must be another way to do this for all the edges at the same time.

So the first image is what I need the edges to look like:
[image: Result]

Here you can see how the edges look like without my manual scaling:
[image: Solid]
[image: Wireframe]

So as you can see from the first image, I need to scale the edges inwards themselves(?) Is essential for me to create this kind of indentation but each edge has a different angle so when I scale them I get a crazy result.

Also, I should apply this for each edge that encircles the barrel.

The barrel is like this:
[image: Barrel Mesh]

And this is the shape of the edges:
[image: Edge angles]

I hope I was able to explain the problem I have.
I really hope that you can help me find the solution, I don't use Blender often, I'm a beginner and sometimes I feel overwhelmed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: I'm doing this operation while using the mirror modifier on the Z-axis

Comment: what does it give if you switch Transform Pivot Point to Individual Origins, then scale? Also if you don't want to scale too much on Z, then first scale only on X and Y with the shift Z constraint while you scale?

Comment: With the individual origins it makes a weird thing inside the barrel. [link](https://ibb.co/MBdVfbc)

Comment: The solution I found so far is to scale first the edges along the X and Y as you said and than to pick manually the top vertex that is not been touched and bring it down. This works good but I was looking for a faster solution.

Comment: Can't really see the problem to be honest. If you loop select each edge by holding Shift-Alt and clicking the edges, then set the transform pivot point to Individual Origins it scales exactly as you show in your first image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shrink/fatten tool is exactly what you need! Select the middle loop of each of the barrel's sides (the one you want to make slightly smaller) and press Alt S. This will shrink the edge loop equally in all directions, giving you the shape you're after.

Comment: OMG YES! YES! THANK YOU !!!!